# Input in a Python text-based GUI (TUI)

Tags: python, user-interface

I have been trying to make my own UI that is text-based in python 2.7, but I thought of an idea about input. So I figured something like this: `input = raw_input("|" + "input: ".center(78) + "|")`, but of coarse, the cursor is way far on the right (just realized it wouldn't work before i even typed it in :P). So, the question is, is how do I put an input in the middle of the screen with text on the same line (on both sides) and have the cursor type after I write "Input: "? And if your wondering, im using this:

```
if True:
    print c + "Hi! This is a text-based GUI!".center(78, h) + c
    print c + "-" * 78 + c
    print v + "OPTIONS".center(78) + v
    print c + "-" * 78 + c
    print v + "1 - Quit".center(78) + v
    for i in range(1, 7):
        print v + " " * 78 + v
    print c + "-" * 78 + c
```

in the interpreter and it looks decent:

```
+------------------------Hi! This is a text-based GUI!-------------------------+
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   OPTIONS                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   1 - Quit                                   |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: I use Windows XP

Comment: Try [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html), there is also a windows version [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: "text-based GUI" is a little bit of a contradiction :)

Comment: Yeah, really I should call it TUI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also try useful built atop `curses` high level framework [`urwid`](http://excess.org/urwid/). With that thing you could do rich and colorful interfaces. *Buttons*, *edit fields*, even *status bars* and *progress bars* and all that you need. To start working you only need Python `curses` installed and `urwid` folder with its sources (you can transfer whole `urwid` library with your application as standalone bundle!). It works even under `cygwin` under Windows XP/7 where is, as we know, no `curses` ports for `Python`.

`urwid` [portfolio](http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html)

No more lowlevel, sometimes very boring `curses` :)

Comment: You can also easily modify (thank to `Python`) source widgets for project or educational needs.

Answer (score 19):

What you need for this sort of text UI is a terminal library that understands the basic layout and capabilities of your screen and the supported input devices.

On Linux (or OSX), the widely recognised standard is `ncurses`.  Python provides a [module](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) to wrap this native library.  However, this (and any package that uses this - e.g. `urwid`) are of limited use on Windows.

In your case, you need to use something else that provides access to the native Win32 console API.  That would either be cygwin, a custom install of PDcurses, or a package like `pywin32`.

Alternatively, if you really don't want to worry about all that OS specific nonsense, you could just install [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics).  This provides a [cross-platform API](http://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/io.html) to place text anywhere on the screen and process keyboard input.  In addition, it provides higher level [widgets](http://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/widgets.html) to create text UIs like this:

[image: Text UI widgets]

Full disclosure: Yes - I am the author of this package.

Comment: Although it reacts kind of slow to keyboard input (as far I have tested it), I have to say that this is pretty impressive. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks.  You might be seeing https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/issues/32 (which is basically that I have overloaded one of the demos).  If not, please feel free to raise a new issue on github.

Answer (score 3):

Adding another option few years after original question. As per the author of [Picotui](https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui):

> Picotui is a Text User Interface (TUI) widget library for Python3. It is known to work with CPython3 and Pycopy (Unix version is officially supported for the latter), but should work with any Python3 implementation which allows to access stdin/stdout file descriptors.

The author also goes on to compare PicoTUI against Urwid. Some interesting points there. I am hoping to use PicoTUI for a project I am looking to start. Admittedly, no first hand experience. Came across this question when looking for answers for my TUI (Text-based UI or Terminal-based UI, much in GUI sense) Python library, so thought of adding this option.

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` function is not nearly sophisticated for this kind of task.

You'd be better of with a library that can control the Unix terminal, such as the [`curses` library](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html). The library essentially lets you build a simple terminal GUI.

If you need more, take a look at [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) as well. Urwid offers more complex GUI widgets for the discerning terminal GUI developer.

You can't use the `curses` module on Windows unfortunately; apparently there are DOS and OS/2 ports but it is primarily a POSIX-only library. On Windows you'll have to use a port such as [`wcurses`](http://code.google.com/p/wcurses/), or you could try the [`console` module](http://www.effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) (the latter drives the Windows CMD console in a similar manner).

Comment: The Console module is out of date of any recent release of windows, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

For a good text-based ui, you could use curses.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

Comment: That is indeed an option, alas too low level -- a'la nuts and bolts. My first professional project after college was a rather big Ncurses UI for a X.400 mailing system written in C some 22 years back. It requires very significant amount of plumbing and "widget" development (a term that I wasn't even aware of at that time), to make anything non-trivial with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all of your answers were great, but I think I can use this for inputs instead of a 3rd party library:

```
c = "+"
h = "-"
print c + h*78 + c
inputa = raw_input(" "*32 + "Input example: ")
print c + h*78 + c
```

which would work for me.