# What to use to make an option menu like Yeoman or Bower for a console application?

Tags: java, python, node.js

I want to create option menus for a terminal application where the user can select in similar way as Yeoman or Bower and also to change the colors of the letters as there is done with those applications.

I searched in internet but I couldn't find any library.

Any recommendation?

Better if there is a library in Python to do this. But also in any other language is fine. I just want to know the different options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ASCII Escape Sequences

This is a language independent option. The way it work is that you print some special characters which are interpreted by the terminal and it changes (for example) the color.

It wouldn't, however, help you with handling the keyboard input.

[More informations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

[Related question on the StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

### ncurses

This is a widely used library on the Linux and it's mostly used in C/C++ applications. However, the Python binding is available too.

[About ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

[ncurses homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

[ncurses tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

[curses in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html)

### lanterna

A Java library similar to ncurses.

[project home](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/)

### blacken

A Java library inspired by ncurses and primarily dedicated for the game development.

[project home](https://code.google.com/p/blacken/)

---

### Related StackOverflow Questions

[Input in a Python text-based GUI (TUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177142/input-in-a-python-text-based-gui-tui)

[Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

[Python Text User Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791261/python-text-user-interface)

Comment: Curses for python is definitely what I was searching. Thanks Tomas

Comment: I use UNIX and curses works fine, but I think it does not work in Windows. This library: [Unicurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyunicurses/) works even in Windows for those that need it.