# Is there a Python module that allows me to create a command line interface like CMD?

Tags: python, tkinter, command-line-interface

I want to create a SQL like language using Python. I want it to look like CMD but always open a proper dedicated tab instead of opening Command prompt to take in the commands. Any recommendations for modules that let you create a command line?

I could use Tkinter and take input from user and process it but I'm curious if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: What about python `input()`? https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/getting-started/input-and-output/tutorial/

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: no I meant like a new tab, not the IDE run tab. thanks anyways

Comment: Use `ttk.Notebook`.

Comment: You want to emulate CMD??? *"Surely there must be some mishtake?"* - Sean Connery. 

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, if you desire a "shell like" UI experience you can try
something more like a TUI (Text User Interface), I recommend :

prompt-toolkit: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit

npyscreen: https://github.com/npcole/npyscreen

Also take a look at this answer: [Input in a Python text-based GUI (TUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177142/input-in-a-python-text-based-gui-tui/37624615)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

use `start (your file's name)` in window cmd when you have the directory contains your file set as directory, so the whole thing would be like:
`cd C:/username/my folder/subfolder/folder containing your python file` 
**don't forget next line here,**
 `start filename.py`

end result should be what you want. and you don't need a module, `input()` is going to cut it.